s3 URL Construct
I have one doubt regarding AWS s3 url constrains. I have 2 cases:
Case 1: https://bucketname.s3.zone.amazonaws.com/
Case 2: https://s3.zone.amazonaws.com/bucketname/
What is the diffrence between this both urls. both are publicly exposed and both are having other files.
Can any one help me to understand why there diffrence in this urls.
I tried gogling but didn't get the proper description.

The difference is between Path-style requests and virtual-hosted–style requests
